# How to write data of different types to binary file

Tags: python, struct, binaryfiles

From what I understand, `I` is an example of a format character which represents an unsigned integer and `f` is used to represent a float

But when I try to write `[120,3.5,255,0,100]` to a binary file as bytes:

```
from struct import pack
int_and_float = [120,3.5,255,0,100]
with open ("bin_file.bin","wb") as f:
    f.write(pack("IfIII",*bytearray(int_and_float)))
```

Output

> TypeError: an integer is required

So is it not possible to store floats and integers as bytes in the same list?

Comment: For your second question (please only ask one at a time!) you can – and should have – read [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Comment: I'm removing the second question, because the alternative is to close this as *too broad*. Posts here should only contain a single question, and 'explain this code to me' without focusing on very specific statements or expressions is also too broad a subject here.

Comment: usr2564301 Thanks for letting me know, I will try to understand it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass in a `bytearray`. Pass in your values *directly*, as arguments:

```
f.write(pack("IfIII", *int_and_float))
```

It is the *`bytearray()` call* that throws the exception you see, and you don't even need this type here:

```
>>> int_and_float = [120,3.5,255,0,100]
>>> bytearray(int_and_float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

`struct.pack()` takes integers (and strings) and produces bytes as output:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack("IfIII", *int_and_float)
b'x\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`@\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Oh, so when is it appropriate to use `bytearray`?

Comment: @Newbie101: not here. `pack()` **produces** bytes, it doesn't consume bytes.

Comment: @Newbie101: `bytearray()` is a mutable version of the `bytes` object (like a `list` is to `tuple`). Their application is broad just like other base types have broad uses.